# How to run npm command correctly in WSL

Tags: node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I got this error when I run the `npm run start` command in wsl

```
/mnt/f/nodejs/npm: line 3: $'\r': command not found
/mnt/f/nodejs/npm: line 5: $'\r': command not found
/mnt/f/nodejs/npm: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'mnt/f/nodejs/npm: line 6: `case `uname` in
```

Comment: Random guess.  Almost looks like some file has the wrong line endings (CRLF `\r\n`) for your platform (which may be expecting just LF `\n`).

Comment: Just to add to @Wyck --- don't try to run from /mnt/ ... You need to have `npm install`'d through WSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you shared files (including `node_modules`) from a Windows install directly into a WSL Linux distro (the `/mnt/f` is highly suspicious). You likely have all your source and did your `npm install` in Windows, but then just tried to run *node* in WSL.  Unfortunately that's a platform mismatch and (as Cody G mentioned in a comment), **you need to `npm install` through WSL**.  This is further evidenced by the fact that the error messages indicate that it's choking on `\r`, which is the first character of a Windows platform CRLF line ending (`\r\n`).  But your Linux distro will want LF endings (`\n`).